# intellij spring boot database connection failed with java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am very first of using intellij and spring boot.(never developed web before until yesterday)
I've tired to make a simple web site following a book's order. But when I keep failing connecting to mysql database.

At first, I saw 'Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.'. So I wrote codes in application.properties and made DatabaseConfiguration class. After that, I had failed message about 'nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist' and warning message about 'Warning:Unable to make the module: board.main, related gradle configuration was not found. Please, re-import the Gradle project and try again.'(I already tried click gradel->re-import and got dialog 'The IDE modules below were removed by the Gradle import:
board.test board.main 
 You can open dialog to select the ones you need to restore.' What should I do next?)

I think I have multiple problem here. Could you help me whit this? Thank you. 
Oh and I tried type 'src/main/resources/application.properties and didn't work)

[image]

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.datasource.hikari.username=root
spring.datasource.hikari.password=1234
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

DatabaseConfiguration

```
package com.example.board.configuration;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig(){
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception{
        DataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
        System.out.println(dataSource.toString());
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

the error

```
"C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=50614:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\ideaprojects\board\build\classes\java\main;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.1.9.RELEASE\b9befb96987c95fe8a6ab4fa79e5ea7a89518fca\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.1.9.RELEASE\7b5c45793e5e6579a09d816c1fa8406a9d7a56e2\spring-boot-devtools-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.9.RELEASE\2063870234eebbda3c09dddf9853477fe9e4a719\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mybatis.spring.boot\mybatis-spring-boot-starter\2.1.0\d1a1b96573ade19ce0cd536e15565d216b05ff83\mybatis-spring-boot-starter-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.9.RELEASE\53bdf52bc28b7e753874e0136fb33c9eab184276\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.9.RELEASE\3f7d1d67669dfa0ea4ff9216afbeef5bc6a58ecb\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.17\53da6afdc5f7b45caaa5bc3627028b2041a36cee\mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.9.RELEASE\45d7afa2d9aab4b2984f2c330f507797fbcf501f\spring-boot-starter-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.11.RELEASE\de7bf0adf13b5e9c4811f95edf18279da193c0c6\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf.extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\36e7175ddce36c486fff4578b5af7bb32f54f5df\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.9.RELEASE\99bef08a0b7fd10ff9827f0f8e6f49b97cbabf7f\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\af73055fc4a103ab347c56e7da5a143d68a0170\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.10.RELEASE\67b6da7852e89bc0df6ce36a263ac4377fe48e27\spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.1.10.RELEASE\f769e9287286f80f6b1d943cc27194ec33d2041c\spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mybatis.spring.boot\mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.0\9acb6ddd5c8e85c753c5e02c40143d80eec25d94\mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mybatis\mybatis\3.5.2\ecdede23e67304e1d47861851dc14cb53c0e369d\mybatis-3.5.2.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mybatis\mybatis-spring\2.0.2\941968ebcb961c460cbb8f0e6fb165051905ca2f\mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.9.RELEASE\aa6d5e0fef585bec64543b9b8f944a94060e710a\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.1.9.RELEASE\b18e7287a82ee06c6bb4e79423c25c05b8303dc1\spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.9.RELEASE\802b562b0c602ae9242b659a28b9bf89ca689b2d\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.1.10.RELEASE\f81a8bb5edeee61484ad916d8bc1dac55e994f1c\spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.1.10.RELEASE\e602c71f7c6e4479fe94d12597563f00c1d94aed\spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.10.RELEASE\48957bfad9656fdba9263539e2fa8f3034939ba8\spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.1.10.RELEASE\c32ebb7fb1be3b733304b7873c31817dd434479a\spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.1.10.RELEASE\6aa17eabf08008f22e7824285663662e7c27e3f4\spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.1.10.RELEASE\7dc657305af97015f96135bfbb5036caf8829070\spring-expression-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.1.10.RELEASE\4349487d80cd1098de6266d1ae99f8d743342d85\spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.11.RELEASE\628ebb91f520053d4120b7b18bf78ff295d57461\thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\3.2.0\6c66db1c636ee90beb4c65fe34abd8ba9396bca6\HikariCP-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\ec62d74fe50689c28c0ff5b35d3aebcaa8b5be68\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\6d37bf7b046c0ce2669f26b99365a2cfa45c4c18\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\c6f06c420ad62d3824b38a06dfdce9fb55ba81ef\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.28\2cd9b264f76e3d087ee21bfc99305928e1bdb443\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.9\4b04126963103216c9c43b0f34bbc36315654204\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.9\a33df137557793b0404a486888dbe049f7abeeeb\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.9\a92facb55a2538e7b2fe14294570a18b823ad431\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.9.9.3\68ddd453458765757fd3ffca9437f9a42d91003e\jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.26\8991b1bd82c5745e95a9161472a92dc1e5c7148e\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.26\6312ba542bc58fa9ee789a43516ce4d862548a6b\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.26\a551f05d3ecf5434eaadd75e0b51519447df124\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.3.Final\d3cfa8d3075fd52884fc82ded5c52b1407f18e6e\jboss-logging-3.3.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\291658ac2ce2476256c7115943652c0accb5c857\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.10.RELEASE\6a2739f86e70d9495314489a99bebff473959fe7\spring-jcl-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\a93ad36df9560de3a5312c1d14f69d938099fa64\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\7b90360afb2b860e09e8347112800d12c12b2a13\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.9.9\bfff5af9fb8347d26bbb7959cb9b4fe9a2b0ca5e\jackson-core-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\2.1.9.RELEASE\c5c010daeb0f909acdc37833a66abb936a67f272\spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.projectlombok\lombok\1.18.10\625fc0055674dff70dbc76efa36d0f2c89b04a24\lombok-1.18.10.jar;C:\Users\absin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\f5e9a2ffca496057d6891a3de65128efc636e26e\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar" com.example.board.BoardApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.9.RELEASE)

2019-10-03 11:09:43.716  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.board.BoardApplication       : Starting BoardApplication on DESKTOP-HR4H108 with PID 8160 (C:\ideaprojects\board\build\classes\java\main started by absin in C:\ideaprojects\board)
2019-10-03 11:09:43.720  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.board.BoardApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-03 11:09:43.780  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-10-03 11:09:43.780  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-10-03 11:09:44.942  WARN 8160 --- [  restartedMain] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.example.board]' package. Please check your configuration.
2019-10-03 11:09:45.377  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-03 11:09:45.396  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-03 11:09:45.396  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.26]
2019-10-03 11:09:45.475  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-03 11:09:45.475  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1695 ms
2019-10-03 11:09:45.524 ERROR 8160 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
2019-10-03 11:09:45.525  WARN 8160 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/example/board/configuration/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
2019-10-03 11:09:45.527  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-03 11:09:45.540  INFO 8160 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-03 11:09:45.549 ERROR 8160 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/example/board/configuration/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.example.board.BoardApplication.main(BoardApplication.java:10) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:955) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:77) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.example.board.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration.dataSource(DatabaseConfiguration.java:27) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.board.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$590ae532.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.board.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$590ae532$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5978b333.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.example.board.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$590ae532.dataSource(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222-2-ojdkbuild]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You didn't include your actual stack trace. (And why are you writing your own Hikari configuration since it's already auto-configured?)

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, what is stack trace...? And I wrote that way because the book i'm using as a guidance used it. Do u have to remove hikari in application.properties or remove DatabaseConfiguration class?? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: The book you're reading is apparently older than Spring Boot, and you should read [the Spring Getting Started guides](https://spring.io/guides). You also need to learn some basics about Java programming; start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: (Spring Boot will automatically configure lots of tools for you with just what's in `application.properties`; you can look for the class `HikariAutoConfiguration` in your IDE to learn more.)

Comment: oh thank you! I added my stack trace now.

Comment: Check this tutorial for setting up the data source with hikaricp: https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp See also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12758#issuecomment-378598342

Comment: @Andrey This article is more to the point: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari